# Almost raw Views output display style plugin?

Tags: views, theming

Has anyone came across a Views display plugin that outputs a very modestly themed markup? I mean:

- no wrapper elements,
- no need to visit each sub-dialog and turn off wrappers, just the minimal output such as link when asked to link, or list items and ul/ol when asked to output a list,
- no template overwriting (usually involves at least 2 files).

I'm not comfortable with writing and debugging raw database queries (which would be the most tempting tactic), neither am I with doing repetitive markup templating. That's why I guess such a display plugin might make sense. Anyone?